# Time for Visa collection after the decision

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I attended an interview with an ECO on October 4 at VFS Islamabad. She said that she'd make a decision the same day and I got the email too. However, I have yet to be contacted by the VFS to collect my passport. How long does it usually take? I have to go away for a week for a reporting assignment (I'm a journalist) so being a little anxious.

Comment: The decision was made on October 4 and I collected the passport on the 16th working day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today is 7 October and you had your interview on 4 October. That means a full two days have passed, it's not enough time.

The processing time for the British mission at Islamabad is shown in this screen capture...

[image]

Source: https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/islamabad-pakistan/visits-visas/general-visit-6-months-or-less

So with a fair wind you should have something back by next Thursday, 13 October.
And they guarantee you'll hear from them by 4 November.

Comment: They guarantee nothing: "actual processing times may vary depending on a range of factors."

Comment: @phoog You'll hear back from them before they overrun their target. It  usually takes the form of an advisory email that processing is taking longer than usual.

Comment: Actually, I applied on September 19 and was called for an interview on October 4. An email regarding the decision was received the same day. What I wanted to ask was, how long does it take the passport to reach the VFS after a decision has been made?

Comment: @UmerAli what did the email say?

Comment: Something like "Your visa application has been processed and the decision is made and it will be
with you in the next few days."

Comment: So are you merely asking how long it takes to transport your stuff back to the VFS?

Comment: @GayotFow yes, I'm asking that because I expect to be away for quite some time so want to learn about the decision before leaving.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46468/discussion-between-umer-ali-and-gayot-fow).